# In C++-17, is there a template deduction guide possible for this constructor?

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there a template deduction guide that would enable the variable `c` to be deduced as type `bar<baz>` just that it is just like variable `b`?

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
struct foo {
  using container = std::vector<T>;
  using creator = std::function<container()>;
};

template<typename T>
struct bar
{
    bar(typename foo<T>::creator) { }
};

struct baz : public foo<baz> {
  static baz::container make_it() { return {}; }
};

int main() {
    bar<baz> b(baz::make_it);
    bar c(baz::make_it); // What is the deduction guide to mimic b?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulty here is due to the relationship between the parameter and the type being deduced being extremely tenuous. It's also unnecessary, due to unnecessary constraints on the function parameter.

I don't see a reason why you *specifically* need to take a `std::function` here. You're already in a template; you could take any invokable type so long as it can be invoked with zero arguments and it returns a container of the appropriate type. So... just do that.

Even if the type is going to store a `std::function` internally, the constructor can perform that conversion itself, rather than shoving it into the function signature.

Once the constructor looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct bar
{
    template<typename Func>
    bar(Func &&f) { }
};
```

Then a deduction guide can be written to create an expectation about the relationship between `Func` and `T`. Namely:

```
template<typename Func>
bar(Func &&f) -> bar<std::invoke_result_t<Func>::value_type>;
```

That works effectively with any invocable type, which are the types you can store in a `std::function<container()>`.

---

However, if you're unwilling to make your code more reasonably generic, you can still do it. In fact, the above deduction guide will work just fine... so long as you have no other constructors that only take one parameter. Then you'll have problems.

The part that's confusing you is `foo`. So get rid of it and list what you're actually doing. Your constructor takes a `std::function`, which can be invoked with zero parameters to return a `vector` prvalue, whose `value_type` is the type you want to deduce. So just say that:

```
template<typename T>
bar(std::function<vector<T>()>) -> bar<T>;
```

Yes, you'll have to repeat the definition of your `baz::container`, but it works. And no, you don't need to make the matching constructor a template.

In fact, you don't even need the deduction guide:

```
template<typename T>
struct bar
{
    bar(std::function<vector<T>()>) { }
};
```